# Why does using ContactKey in MobileStudio SMS messages return nothing

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

My SMS message contains the following message:

```
Your ContactKey is %%ContactKey%%
```

When I trigger the message (via Text-Response) I get back the following message:

> Your ContactKey is

I know there is at least one Contact in Mobile Studio thats attached to the number I sent the text from. Why is this not working as expected?

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2018_sms_contactkey.htm&type=0) says you can use ContactKey.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple people with the same mobile number present in Mobile Connect.

When you're using the Text Response template, Marketing Cloud would not know which subscriber key to send.

If you would want to obtain the key for this template, you would need to do a lookup to your data extension where you are storing contacts based on the mobile number personalization string that's functioning in the Text Response context.